# Consider the following vector subspaces of $P_2(\mathbb R)$:

Tags: linear-algebra

$U =\bigl\{ p(x) = a + bx + cx^2 ∈ P_2(\mathbb R)\mid a − 2c = 0 \bigr\}$

$W = [1 − x , x − x^2]$

Determine a basis for the subspace $U + W$.

I had no issues to find a basis for $U$, but I don't really know how to find one for the sum of the two subspaces.

Comment: Can you clarify?  What is $P2(R)$?  What is $P2(IR)$?  At first I thought you meant quadratic polynomials with real coefficients, but then what is $W$?

Comment: Pardon me, I'm not really good at formatting yet. $P2(R)$ does stand for the quadratic polynomials, and $W$ is a subspace defined by the generators $1−x$ and  $x−x^2$

Comment: Well, what is the dimension of $P_2(\mathbb R)$?  What is the dimension of $U$, of $W$?  What about $U+W$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Can you find two linearly independent vectors in $U$? Can you deduce what $U+W$ is?

Comment: Yes, I found $2 + x^2$ and $x$ as generators for $U$. Would a basis for $U+W$ be simply $[2 + x^2, x, 1-x, x-x^2]$? I feel like I need to prove that this works as a basis, but is it enough to show that they're linearly independent?

Comment: No it can't be a basis, as there are 4 vectors in a $3$-dimensional space, but what can you say about $U+W$?